# Creating multiple instances of a model from another model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

How would I create multiple instances of a model from another model related by a foreign key? Example code below:

```
import itertools

class Table(models.Model):
    color = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')

    def create_chairs(self, num, style):
        for _ in itertools.repeat(None,num):
            c = Chair(style=style, table=self)


class Chair(models.Model):
    style = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    table = models.ForeignKey('Table')
```

Trying to use `t1 = Table(color="blue", create_chairs={"style": 'natural', "num": 4})` which would create a Table object that has 4 chairs. Should models.py even contain logic like this or should it all be done from views.py?

Comment: What is `create_chairs={"style": 'natural', "num": 4}`? How does it work?

Comment: it's supposed to be the method of the Table class, so I could call it from my table objects.

Answer (score 1):

One problem with your current method is that you are creating chairs but not assigning them to anything, so there are chairs with no table.

Django provides a built-in to take care of this, so you don't need a specific method:

```
t1 = Table(color='Blue')

chairs = [Chair(style=y) for y in ['Natural']*4]
for chair in chairs:
    t1.chair_set.add(chair)
```

If you want to do this in a separate method, you can add this to your `models.py`, *outside* of any class, at the very end:

```
def musical_chairs(table, num_chairs=4, style='Normal'):
    chairs = [Chair(style=s) for s in [style]*num_chairs]
    for chair in chairs:
        table.chair_set.add(chair)
```

Comment: I'd like to do this in a separate method, but why can't it be in my Table class? And if I did add it, how would it be called t1.musical_chairs(4)? And I've never seen the syntax `[Chair(style=s) for s in [style]*num_chairs]` before, could link it somewhere in the docs so I can read about it?

Comment: It's a list comprehension and a core thing to grasp when coding Python. There are numerous sources available with googles help. Furthermore you can put it in your Table class. Be sure to switch `table` for `self` though.

Comment: If you put it in your table class, you are recreating functionality already available as part of django. This is a bad idea, don't do it. In fact you shouldn't have it as a separate method anyway - it will just be syntax sugar over a method that is already provided and is quite concise.

Comment: @Burnhan & limelights thanks for the sugar, I didn't quite understand the code but I'm going to start reading up on list comprehensions right after this. Not really sure who to award this ? to, Luan's is easily understood but I'm learning something new from yours.

Answer (score 1):

As they said. create_chair is a `method`, not a `model attribute`, then you have to create a `instance/object` of your `Table` model and so add new `chairs`.

```
t1 = Table.objects.create(color="blue")
t1.create_chairs(style='natural', num=4)
```

---

And you have to change your method, to make the `save()` trough the `create()` method.

```
def create_chairs(self, num, style):
    for _ in itertools.repeat(None, num):
        Chair.objects.create(style=style, table=self)
```

Comment: This got me a little further, but in the debugger I get `Integrity Error: myapp_chair.table_id may not be null`. Is there something wrong with passing in the "self" reference?

Comment: Solved the integrity error, forgot to specify the num argument in my call to create_chairs. I like the simplicity of your answer as it was easy to understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`create_chairs()` is a method, not an attribute.  You can create the table and chairs this way:

```
t1 = Table(color="blue")
t1.create_chairs(4, 'natural')
```

Yes, this relational logic belongs in the model.  By the way, the `for` statement can be replaced with:

```
for _ in range(num):
```

Now storing all of this furniture is another step.  After each entity is created, you need to `put()` them so they exist after the program ends.